# Nuxt: generate static app to an unknown base path?

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm fairly certain the answer is "No", but...

Using `target: 'static'`, is there a configuration to generate a "portable" generated app - without using hash mode for the router? I've tried `router: { base: './' }`, but that still generates root-relative hrefs ("/about", "/") where I'm looking for relative paths ("about", "../").

````
export default {
  target: 'static',
  // ssr: false,
  router: {
    base: './'
  },```
````